# How to implement csvwriter in python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, csv, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have an app that works to write a csv as a response to a specific URL call. But, I don't know how to escape characters.

Right now, my code looks like this

```
import csv
class ReturnCSV(BaseHandler):
        def get(self, group_id):
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
            self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=scenarios.csv"
            self.write(','.join(header))     #header is a list defined elsewhere

            for scenario in list_of_scenarios:
                #do stuff
                self.write('\r\n' + ','.join(output)))
```

This gets me the expected output, except that it doesn't escape special characters. I figured I need to implement csv.writer with QUOTE_ALL, but when trying that, I get an `IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename)`

```
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=scenarios.csv"
    with open('scenarios.csv', 'w') as output:
        row = ','.join(header)
        wr = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(row)

        for scenario in list_of_scenarios:
            #do stuff
            wr.writerow(output)
```

Comment: Can you write it directly to `self.response.out` or possibly even `self.response`?  IIRC, `self.response.out` is sufficiently file-like to work with `csv`.

Comment: I figured out that if I don't try to open the file and use output = StringIO.StringIO() instead, I can use self.write(output.getvalue())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, got it to work if I don't try to open the file and then I take out all the `','.join` that I was doing to manually create CSV.

```
output = StringIO.StringIO()
row = header #header created elsewhere
wr = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
wr.writerow(row)
for scenario in list_of_scenarios:
    # do stuff
    wr.writerow(datarow)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=scenarios.csv"
self.write(output.getvalue())
```